# IntelliJ IDEA - JPanel in JScrollpane no content shown

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea, jframe

I have a JScrollPane which needs to be filled with data coming from a DB. 
The panels are made with IntelliJ IDEA.

```
public class NodeViewer extends JFrame {
private NodeManager _manager;
private JScrollPane _container;

public NodeViewer(NodeManager manager) {
    setVisible(false);
    pack();
    setContentPane(_container);
    setSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));
    setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());
    _manager = manager;
}

public void LoadData() {
    _container.removeAll();
    LoadNodes(_manager.GetAllNodes());
}

private void LoadNodes(List<Object> nodes) {
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.size(); i++) {

        JPanel newPanel = new NodePanel((INode) nodes.get(i), i);
        getContentPane().add(newPanel);
    }
}
```

This is the scrollpane, which will create a NodePanel for every iterations, and add it to the scrollpane.

```
public class NodePanel extends JPanel {
private JPanel _nodeContainer;
private JLabel _personName;
private JLabel _albumName;
private JLabel _bandName;
private JLabel _memberSince;
private JLabel _personBirth;
private JLabel _releasedOn;
private JButton _deletePerson;
private JButton _deleteBand;
private JButton _deleteAlbum;

public NodePanel(INode node, int i) {
    setVisible(true);
    setBounds(150, (i * 250) + (i * 25), 700, 250);
    setSize(new Dimension(700, 250));
    setLayout(new GridLayout());
    setBackground(Color.BLUE);
    SetContent(node);
}
```

The node panel extends the JPanel.
The panels itself are created: http://gyazo.com/6e55dc85c177f8599f16d3bdbeb6c36e as is seen on the screenshot. The content however is not to be seen. All JLabels from the NodePanel are set by setText().
I have tried to repaint, revalidate almost everything, but I can't seem to find what is wrong. I also tried different layout types, but that didn't seem to matter either.

Answer (score 2):

a few points

---

- `public class NodeViewer extends JFrame {`, don't to extend `JFrame`, create this Obejct as local variable (as is `private NodeManager _manager;`)

---

code ordering is very important, e.g.

- `JFrame.setVisible(false);`, why is visibility set to `false`, and for `JFrame.setVisible(true);` this code line should be the last code line in the `public NodeViewer(NodeManager manager) {`
- `JFrame.pack();` should be before code line `JFrame.setVisible(true);`, this code line is about to `getPrefererSize` from all `JFrame` childs in 1st level (`JScrollPane` in this case)
- `setSize(new Dimension(1000, 700));`, rather to set `getPrefererSize` for `JScrollPane`, then `JFrame.pack();` accepts this value as its `PrefererSize`
- `setLayout(new ScrollPaneLayout());` take this specifics `LayoutManager` as designated exclusivelly for `JScrollPane` (in `API`s, `BasicsScrollPaneUI` or `UIManager`), is not designated as `LayoutManager` for `JFrame`

---

main problems

- `setContentPane(_container);` != `getContentPane().add(newPanel);`, maybe to match with your original topics
- `_container.removeAll();`, `JSrollPane` isn't container, option is explained in last point, otherwise to use `JSrollPane.setVieportView(something);`
- overide `getPreferredSize` for `public class NodePanel extends JPanel {` instead of useless code lines `setVisible(true);` and `setBounds(150, (i * 250) + (i * 25), 700, 250);` and `setSize(new Dimension(700, 250));`

---

direct solution,

- isn't easier to use `JComponent.setText("")` for all `JTextComponents` in `public class NodePanel extends JPanel {` rather than to remove and then to add the same `JPanel` instead of reseting for value, something hidden behind `SetContent(node);` should be refreshed with some default, initial value too